# Editing the portion of canvas

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to cut the portion on canvas, and paste it somewhere else in the canvas(like Ms Paint).. is it possible? Please suggest me a way to do it

Answer (score 1):

A Canvas does not hold an image. It is a utility for drawing onto something else. The "something else" is the device's screen for the Canvas passed to onDraw, but you can create a Bitmap and then create a Canvas that draws into that Bitmap. Then you can paint a portion of the Bitmap (using another Canvas) into the destination to do a copy/paste operation.

Comment: hi ted,I have done like that only.. But my problem is how to cut a portion of bitmap using touch event??